# XCode CarPlay simulator change resolution

Tags: xcode, carplay

According to Apple docs

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/using_the_carplay_simulator?language=objc

this should enable some additional options for the CarPlay simulator

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator CarPlayExtraOptions -bool YES
```

but i don't see any options available and would like to change the resolution of the CarPlay simulator, as the default is too small, how to change the CarPlay simulator resolution?

Comment: Can't you see a dialog window when selecting I/O→External Displays→CarPlay... ? You should be able to set width/height and Scale

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so after

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator CarPlayExtraOptions -bool YES
```

i needed to restart the mac, then after selecting CarPlay in I/O menu a settings dialog pop ups...

note that changing the resolution is a little buggy and you have to once again restart the simulator for the change to work proper